# Dynamic token handling of a gis application

Tags: dynamic, jmeter, token

I m doing performance testing of a gis application using jmeter in which lot of map tiles load as i login to the application.each tile is a http request containing a dynamic token in its header which expires in 15 mins.I know handling of dynamic token using regex where i replace the token with a regex but problem here is that there are huge no.of map tiles so replacing each token one by one is not feasible option...can anyone suggest how do I change all the token at once or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

[image]

so if you move it 1 level up (to be at the same position as your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler) you will need to perform the change at one place only